# Adding Jar file from HDFS to Hive

Tags: hadoop, jar, hive, hiveql

When I execute the code below:

```
ADD JAR hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

in Hive I get following error:

```
Error while processing statement: Failed to read external resource hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why?

Comment: Try `ADD JAR hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;`

Comment: Have you uploaded the JAR file into the path you referring in HDFS. if not please download the JAR file and upload in HDFS